# Unable to use Auth0 to get delegation token

Tags: authentication, angular, auth0

In my Angular2 app, I want to use Auth0 to get a delegation token so I could use it to custom sign into firebase. I followed the sample [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs2-systemjs-sample/tree/master/01-Login) to setup my Auth0 service and got it working.

The problem I'm having now is getting my delegation token and sign into Firebase with it. The example [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/fireteller) shows how it's done, but I'm getting an EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'auth0' of undefined when I try to declare my auth0 instance and use it to get my delegation token. What did I do wrong?

In my index.html I included the following scripts:

```
<script src="http://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.7/lock.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/w2/auth0-7.4.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried in my terminal to install auth0:

```
npm install auth0
npm install auth0-js
```

My auth service currently looks like this:

```
// app/auth.service.ts

import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

// Avoid name not found warnings
declare var Auth0Lock: any;
declare var Auth0: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID', 'AUTH0_DOMAIN', {});

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
      // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
      this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error:any, profile:any){
        if(error){
          throw new Error(error);
        }

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));

        //options to be used with auth0 instance to get delegation token
        var options = {
        id_token : authResult.idToken,
        api : 'firebase',
        scope : 'openid name email displayName',
        target: 'AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'
        };

        //----->ERROR HERE, can't read auth0 property
        this.auth0.getDelegationToken(options, function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
          if(!err){
          this.af.auth().signInWithCustomToken(result.id_token).catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  }

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to create `auth0` instance as shown [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/fireteller/blob/master/public/app.js#L81)

```
var auth0 = new Auth0({ domain : AUTH0_DOMAIN, clientID: AUTH0_CLIENT_ID });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this issue. I was stuck on this exact same problem and I think it has got to do with typscript importing of the auth0 module. Instead of using the auth0 module I simply made an HTTP POST request to my Auth0 account's delegation endpoint:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post('https://<Your domain>/delegation',
    {
      "client_id": "<Your client ID>",
      "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
      "id_token": <Your auth0 Id Token>,
      "target": "Your client ID",
      "scope": "openid",
      "api_type": "<Your delegation choice (mine was "aws")>",
    }, options)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => localStorage.setItem('awsToken', JSON.stringify(data.Credentials)),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
```

This will store the acquired credentials in your browser's local storage. Note: there may be some additional parameters required by Firebase that I am unaware of as I am using AWS. Also you will need the following imports for this HTTP request:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers,RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```